# TableView Error Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to coding so I not sure how to fix this error:

```
private let cellReuseIdentifier = "ArticleViewCell"
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = ArticleViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Downcast from 'UITableViewCell?' to 'UITableView only warps optionals; did you mean to use "!"?
```

I tried changing the `?` to `!` put it get an error also.

Comment: See what the return type of dequeue is.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```

Also do not forget to return the cell.

```
return cell
```

Comment: This will only work if the OP has registered the cell class (or is using a Storyboard which will register the cell class for them)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier) as! <ClassName>
```

Where "ClassName" is the name of the class for the article tableview cell.

Comment: You don't want the !, that will crash since `dequeueCellWithReuseIdentifier` can return nil. You need to conditionally unwrap the return with ?  The if statement then handles the nil case. It is probably better that the op register the cells clas against the reuse identifier and then use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath`

Comment: In my opinion, it is one of those rare instances when I use an `!` (yes it can crash). `cellForRowAtIndexPath` requires you to return a cell, so what happens when you use `?` and a nil is returned. cellForRowAtIndexPath` needs non-optional. I agree you need to register the cell. You don't need to dequeue based on the indexpath unless you want a different cell based on the indexpath. You can dequeue as for the tableview

Comment: Then you should clarify your answer and include the need to register the cell class.   If you refer to the OP code they are clearly using the 'old style' cell dequeue where `nil` can be returned and the next step is to allocate a new cell, and so your code *will* crash, but with a ? it will work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to unwrap it at all:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier)
```

Answer (score -1):

after you create cell, when you use it you should add a "!" after the cell such as:

```
return cell!
```